# Car is running louder and slower than usual

Tags: engine, toyota, noise, corolla, old-cars

I drove at an expressway which requires 60 - 100 kph, after about 20mins of driving, my car started to run louder than usual and 10mins later it's running slower even for a 5th gear. Please help. My car is an old model, Toyota Corolla 1992. Thank you so much!

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! W

Comment: Was the sound do to higher rpm? How many km since last clutch replacement. Can test clutch by activating park brake & giving gas in 2nd gear c if it runs